# With the new (Feb 2022) NASA SpaceX Crew Dragon contract extension, how much per flight?

Tags: spacex, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2

NASA [awarded](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-awards-spacex-additional-crew-flights-to-space-station) flights 7, 8, and 9 for Crew Dragon in an extension of the existing contract, bringing the total value to \$3,490,872,904 . We know that in 2014 SpaceX was awarded about $2.6 billion to develop and fly Crew Dragon, at least the first two Demo and first operational flight were included in there.

Bottom line, how much did these 3 additional flights actually cost?

Comment: Was wondering the same.  Simple math suggests about 270 million per missions, which seems really high.  Like 70 plus a seat.  That seems really high.

Comment: @geoffc not too far from [the Inspector General's guess from 2019](https://oig.nasa.gov/docs/IG-20-005.pdf) ($55m per seat)

Comment: I'm not sure it is that simple. I'm wondering if the first 6 missions (Plus two demos + IFA) were all included in the original $2.6 billion...

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that NASA is paying Boeing some money for the additional Orbital Flight Test required due to the failure of the first one. If that were true, I would assume that SpaceX would also be paid for their tests.

Comment: [Multiple](https://techcrunch.com/2022/02/28/nasa-extends-spacexs-commercial-crew-contract-by-three-missions-for-900-million/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAMS6vxwdCSIl6mLHqxFvPfSlG2zCjS68g1toS9tJKjmZt75i1KbK-TL_4gzsM3vQO0Q1PWNm5aBFwr4kgrApMeyuLZLLu-NGrk3riDX8imfAVywwQt9-nuFX-SYalWspFn4L0Dn_DvE_UQOwudomVIE6YDAkYoF8cgVfpEK3099V) [sites](https://www.ns-businesshub.com/transport/nasa-spacex-commercial-crew-contract-extension/) claim a \$900 million contract extension, or \$300 million per flight, or \$75 million per seat.

Comment: I suspect there might be some rounding in that \$900 million number.

Comment: @geoffc Even if it is \$75 million per seat, that is less than Russia was charging as of late for Soyuz launches. Moreover, there are added benefits in that the money largely stay in the US and that some of the money even comes back to the US government in the form of taxes.

Comment: Jeff Foust recently posted at [SpaceNews](https://spacenews.com/nasa-awards-spacex-three-additional-commercial-crew-missions/) that "Agency spokespersons did not respond to questions about the contract March 1 and March 2." However, he also reported that "according to a federal contract database, NASA issued a \$776 million modification for the contract Feb. 28 for the three flights." If that is true, that is a per-seat cost of \$64.7 million.

Comment: @DavidHammen If that is the case, that's about where I would expect. $75 million per seat seems a bit high...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto \$75 million per seat is a bit high, but SpaceX is now the only game in town, at least for a while (until the situation in Ukraine is resolved or until Starliner or a human-rated DreamChaser flies). This means SpaceX can charge whatever they want -- within reason.